# Compare MySQL dates when stored as datetime

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried several mySQL queries to compare a column of dates stored as datetime. I need to create several different `queries` depending on what action is taken on the form. Below is an example of the sql I have created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW franchise_filter AS SELECT * FROM `c_data`.`franchise_leads`    WHERE `lead_added` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 3 Months)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW franchise_filter AS SELECT * FROM `c_data`.`franchise_leads` WHERE `lead_added` <= 2012-06-27 00:00:00
```

In the second example the date is supplied by PHP using:

```
date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($date_now, "+6 months"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close: Use

```
... WHERE `lead_added` <= "2012-06-27 00:00:00"
```

(mind the quotes) and

```
... WHERE `lead_added` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND NOW()
```

Comment: Those bloomin' quotes! In the second example (BETWEEN AND), I dont need to convert to time stamps?

Comment: No. The data type of the column is `DTAETIME`, so is the datataype of `NOW()`

Answer (score 0):

```
BETWEEN NOW() + INTERVAL 3 Months AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function, e.g. -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(date_time_field) <= '2012-06-27';
```

Also, you can use a [CURRENT_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) function instead of NOW().